# How to disable VSCode Chrome debugging "Restore Tabs" warning?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

When starting Chrome via the VSCode debugger, when I shut down the process, Chrome thinks it crashed, and in every debug session when it starts up again it gives me the "Restore Tabs" warning. I need to disable it during debugging / for the debugged instances of Chrome, otherwise it tends to just sit around and wait for that dialog to be dismissed and the debug session doesn't start up.

So... how do I disable it the in VSCode launch configuration?

Answer (score 2):

In the launch.config use the `runtimeArgs` option with the Chrome runtime argument `--disable-session-crashed-bubble`:

```
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch web app with Chrome Debugger",
  "runtimeArgs": ["--disable-session-crashed-bubble"],
  ...
```